# powershell ls errors certain folders / files

Tags: powershell, ls, get-childitem, system.io.file

I'm looking at doing a recursive Get-ChildItem -r to get lastWriteTime, length and group for count by extension.

I get a bunch of errors, e.g., 'Get-ChildItem : Could not find item C:\Pics & Videos\Thumbs.db'.

I was thinking some folders or filenames had special characters in the name of the folder or file. I was able to encapsulate in quotes to correct some of the erroring files, but not all.

[System.IO.File]::Exists("C:\Pics & Videos\Thumbs.db") gave me a True, but
Get-ChildItem "C:\Pics & Videos\Thumbs.db" gave me the error.

I'm going to look at [System.IO.Fileinfo], but wonder if anyone can answer why I get these errors using Get-ChildItem aka ls?

Thanks

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in question 9508375.

```
get-childitem -literalpath
```

This handles the problem with special characters in the name.

Answer (score 0):

`Thumbs.db` is (typically) a hidden file. By default `Get-ChildItem` doesn't look for hidden files. Pass `-Force` (`-Hidden` shows *only* hidden items):

```
PS> get-childitem .\Thumbs.db
Get-ChildItem: Could not find item C:\[...]\Thumbs.db.
PS> get-childitem .\Thumbs.db -Force

    Directory: C:\[...]

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a-h-          24/12/2016    11:17          13824 Thumbs.db
```

Comment: Thanks  I like the -Hidden method.  Thumbs.db was an example and kinda figured it was special in it's own regard, but I get errors on xls, doc and such.   I will try the -hidden in case some users put that attribute on other files.

Comment: `-Hidden` reports _only_ hidden items. By contrast, `-Force` _includes_ hidden items.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found what I was looking for.  With $Path a full path to the starting folder I want to recursively get file info from.

```
[IO.Directory]::EnumerateFileSystemEntries($path,"*.*","AllDirectories") | 
ForEach { [System.IO.FileInfo]"$_" }
```

Other suggestions are welcome that might be faster.  I'm looking at millions of files over 4500 folders.  get-childitem only was able to get 60% of the files with 40% being errors without values.  This is for one department and there are several.

Answer (score 0):

Tested: get-childItem vs EnumerateFiles vs Explorer vs TreeSize

```
$path = "P:\Proxy Server Files\Dept1\sxs\"
```

First choice was slow.  I get errors; so I added the error count as a guess.

```
$error.clear()
(get-ChildItem $path -r -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).count 
1333
$error.count
256
```

Second choice was much faster but gave less numbers.

```
$error.clear()
([IO.Directory]::EnumerateFileSystemEntries($path,"*.*","AllDirectories")).count
1229
$error.count
0
```

Trying to only look at files recursively again I get errors; so I added the error count as a guess.

```
$error.clear()
(get-ChildItem $path -r -file).count
558
$error.count
256
```

Looking at just files I get a much lower number that expected.

```
([IO.Directory]::EnumerateFileSystemEntries($path,"*.*","AllDirectories") | ForEach { [System.IO.FileInfo]"$_" }| Where Mode -NotMatch "d").count
108
```

Tried another method but same result.

```
([IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path,"*.*","AllDirectories")| ForEach { [System.IO.FileInfo]"$_" }| Where Mode -NotMatch "d").count
108
```

From Windows Eplorer I see 37 files and 80 folders.

TreeSize.exe shows 1175 files on 775 folders.

I'm not sure what count to believe.  Admin rights used to get all counts.

Any ideas why so many different results?

Comment: This is a different question.

Comment: Classic admin level dir command with options /s /a-d showed 454 files.  With my secondary creds I see 558 files.  Why is it so hard to get an accurate and consistent count.

Comment: It does fit another question but also applies to this one.  I was not able to see thumb.db via get-childItem so my number of files is not correct.  I have many doc, xls files that are also not showing up in my count of files due to some files cannot be retrieved for lastwritetime, length, etc...